# Script not showing variable in html element

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code and its supposed to show the string in the script element but it only shows [object Object] and its supposed to show ["John", 90]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="student-list">Hello</h1>

<script>
    var student = [
    {name: "John", grade: "90"}
    ];

    var studentl = document.getElementById("student-list");
    studentl.innerHTML = student;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ``document.getElementById("student-list").textContent = `["${student[0].name}", ${student[0].grade}]`;``.

Comment: You can use: ```studentl.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(student);```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian for the code that worked!